# If you know $N=a^2+b^2$ how to compute $a$ and $b$ for large $N$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Having tested that $N$ is such that every exponent of a prime in the prime factorisation of $N$ congruent to  $3
\bmod 4$ is even. Then for large $N$ can we find $a$ and $b$, such that $N=a^2+b^2\;\;$?

An example I have seen answered goes like this $$ 58261= 7^2\cdot 29\cdot 41$$ $$29=2^2+5^2$$
$$41=4^2+5^2$$ Now I don't understand how the next step is found:

$29\cdot 41=(8-25)^2+(10+20)^2=17^2+30^2. $  $$\Rightarrow 58261=(7\cdot 17)^2+(7\cdot 30)^2=119^2+210^2$$

I've been asked to try a similar example with $11834=2\cdot 61\cdot 97$. Any pointers? I can find the squares individually for the primes but can't put them together.

Comment: try $N=21.......$

Comment: Ah I see.... think I probably have should have specified that every exponent of a prime in the prime factorisation of $N$ congruent to $3\equiv mod \; 4$ has to be even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the identity:
$$ (a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2) = (ac - bd)^2 + (ad + bc)^2$$

(Also, you have a typo since $10^2 + 20^2$ is not $30^2$.)